# web3.js - Retrieving an item in a Smart Contract array

Tags: solidity, web3js

In Solidity, I have an array declared as follows:

```
uint[] public moveTimeStamp;
```

In web3 JavaScript I would like to retrieve the element at position 0 in the array. I tried to access it like this:

```
var contract = web3.eth.contract(interface);
var instance = contract.at("0x1234...");
instance.moveTimeStamp(0).call(function(err, result) {....
```

Web3js says this isn't correct. What should I be writing after `moveTimeStamp`?

I tried the following:

```
instance.moveTimeStamp(0)
instance.moveTimeStamp([0])
```

...which doesn't work.

This is how I call it:

```
var contract = web3.eth.contract(interface); 
var instance = contract.at(contractaddress);
instance.callTimeStamp(0).call(function(err, result) {...
```

And this is the error I get

```
TypeError: instance.callTimeStamp(...).call is not a function
```

And if you will like see that the `callTimeStamp` array really does contain something, you can go to https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x86c9d3abf13d25ced87c0d00331667ac44c04a89#readContract to read the contract variables.

Comment: "Web3 says this isn't correct." Does that mean you're seeing an error message? If so, what's the error?

Comment: Added the error message and the link to my contract on Ropsten.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if creating an `instance` changes the semantics of how `call` works, but based on [the web3 1.0 docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call) it looks like `web3` expects the call to be shaped like:

`<contract>.methods.<methodName>([...methodArgs]).call(callback)`

Otherwise it looks like your call is correct, [the Solidity docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#getter-functions) seem to suggest that a getter for an array takes a `uint` for the requested index.

Comment: This is how I call it: 

var contract = web3.eth.contract(interface);
var instance = contract.at(contractaddress);
instance.callTimeStamp(0).call(function(err, result) {...

And this is the error I get

TypeError: instance.callTimeStamp(...).call is not a function

And if you will like see that the callTimeStamp array really does contain something, you can go to https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x86c9d3abf13d25ced87c0d00331667ac44c04a89#readContract to read the contract variables.

Comment: The getter method will have the same name as the variable declared, so your original `.moveTimeStamp(0)` was correct.  What happens if you change it to `instance.methods.moveTimeStamp(0).call()`?

Answer (score 0):

Solidity tooling has improved a lot since 2018! We have developed a tool called `cast`, as part of the [Foundry suite](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/) which lets you do this from CLI.

[Here's how you can install Foundry](https://book.getfoundry.sh/getting-started/installation)

To solve your problem, you would simply do `cast call 0x86c9d3abf13d25ced87c0d00331667ac44c04a89 "moveTimestamp(uint256)" 0 --rpc-url <...>`

See here for more docs around [`cast call`](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/cast/cast-call). Under the hood it performs an `eth_call`, which is equivalent to your web3.js code (if it worked).

For anyone following this thread, Ropsten is [deprecated](https://blog.ethereum.org/2022/06/21/testnet-deprecation) since the merge, so the above won't work.